# What is the Impact of ALLOW FILTERING on Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

According to official Cassandra blog, ALLOW FILTERING is highly inefficient. But if for some reason one has to use such query, what would be the impact on other applications that use Cassandra to get data? Would only the thread(s) that are busy fetching rows for my query would be slow, or would whole Cassandra would be slow, and consequently, all other applications that are getting data from Cassandra will get their response slow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will likely affect the whole node. A problem around it is that your one query with a limit of 10 will not just read 10 records and return, but (possibly) a LOT of data. It is possible to make efficient ALLOW FILTERING queries, which things like the spark driver (token limited queries per token range or within a partition) can do. I would very strongly recommend not even attempting it though. It might work at first but your poor operations team will curse your name.

With faster disks, the obj allocations since this is unthrottled will cause *serious* GC overhead. This is very similiar to the issue seen when using queues or a lot of tombstones, the JVM building and throwing away the rows overruns the allocation rate the garbage collector can keep up with without longer pauses (early promotions, fragmentation in cms, allocation spikes messing up g1 younggen ratios).

If cross partitions, like with normal range queries, the coordinator will attempt to estimate the ranges it will need to read and the replicas for them to fan out with some limited concurrency. Its a rough estimate because it only has its own data to extrapolate but when the data is then further filtered and not just "number of partitions within range" its likely gonna be wrong and underestimate. Most likely it will query one range at a time, querying next replica set range if it isnt met. With vnodes this can be a very long list, and sequentially walking them will likely not complete within timeout. Luckily this will impact mostly just the one query, but it is still essentially reading the entire dataset off disk from every replica set in the cluster from **1** query. If you make 100/sec the cluster will probably be hosed.

Comment: Chris Thanks for the great answer. So you are basically saying every other application would get affected? They all will get their data slow? Or sometimes their queries will timeout? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: It will likely affect everything negatively, possibly the entire cluster. but it really depends on data model and what the query is and how often queried.